# Can Neo4j 3.5.1 (latest version) be accessed using the Neo4j Tinkerpop API?

Tags: neo4j, tinkerpop3

I am embedding Neo4j Community Edition (v 3.5.1) in a Java app and trying to open a graph using the Tinkerpop API. I am encountering an exception when doing so and suspect that the latest version of the Neo4j Tinkerpop API Implementation is not compatible with Neo4J 3.5.1. Is this correct? Are there workarounds?

Specifically, I am trying to use the following: Neo4j CE 3.5.1, Tinkerpop 3.3.5, and the Neo4j Tinkerpop API Implementation 0.7-3.2.3. I suspect that the Neo4j Tinkerpop API version is not compatible with the latest version of Neo4j but the API version has not been updated in well over a year. I have also tried using Neo4j CE 3.4.11 and that too is not working.

However, I am able to get Neo4j CE 3.2.13 to work with Neo4j Tinkerpop API 0.6-3.2.2 with no issues.

My POM includes the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>tinkerpop</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-gremlin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.7-3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

In my Java code, I am trying to open a graph as follows:

```
    Configuration configuration = new BaseConfiguration();
    configuration.addProperty("gremlin.graph", "org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph");
    configuration.addProperty("gremlin.neo4j.directory", "/neo4jpoc");

    graph = Neo4jGraph.open(configuration);
```

When trying to open a graph using this, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.neo4j.configuration.LoadableConfig: Provider org.neo4j.kernel.impl.enterprise.configuration.EnterpriseEditionSettings could not be instantiated
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:232)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:185)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:384)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
.....
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.neo4j.kernel.configuration.Settings.setting(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/function/Function;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/graphdb/config/BaseSetting;
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.enterprise.configuration.EnterpriseEditionSettings.<clinit>(EnterpriseEditionSettings.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
.....
```

Again, I have no issues using Neo4j v. 3.2.13 but would like to use the latest version or at least v. 3.4.11.

Thank you. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Neo4j version is defined by `neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl` which appears to have been updated to Neo4j 3.4.10:

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-tinkerpop-api-impl/tree/3.4

That version would need to be updated in neo4j-gremlin and then tested:

https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/blob/67764ba23d67d9f62048c22e8bbcefb87463584e/neo4j-gremlin/pom.xml#L120

Ideally that would have happened on the TinkerPop 3.4.0 release which just occurred last week, but depending on the nature of any changes required for the upgrade it might be fine to apply it for 3.4.1. A pull request for this work would be happily considered, but you could obviously just build your own TinkerPop artifacts from source with this change.

Comment: Thanks Stephen for the reply. I was able to get this to work. However, one of my objectives in using the the latest version of Neo4j was to be able to persist vertices with date property values which Neo4j supports from version 3.4. However, I am unable to do so via a Gremlin even after using the latest version which is now 3.5.1.

Comment: as a side note this upgrade is becoming official: https://github.com/apache/tinkerpop/pull/1042 - as for your comment, you say there's a problem but don't say what it is.

Comment: Sorry Stephen... let me be clearer. I am trying to use a Gremlin traversal to store a native datetime value i.e.`.property("propName", new Date())` When doing so, I get the exception: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property value [Fri Jan 18 06:55:45 EST 2019] is of type class java.util.Date is not supported` The latest version of Neo4j supports native date types but I wonder if that's only when using Cypher.

Comment: What happens if you pass a raw `DateValue`: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/3.4.12/community/values/src/main/java/org/neo4j/values/storable/DateValue.java

Comment: I hadn't tried that earlier. It does indeed work. Thanks. Having said that, I was looking to stick to pure Tinkerpop (i.e. no Neo4j imports). I don't understand why the Neo4j Gremlin API implementation doesn't accept one of the standard Java date types and map to the underlying type under the hood. If you can help me understand this, I'd appreciate it. Nonetheless, many thanks for your help Stephen.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with TinkerPop. My guess is that Neo4j doesn't accept pure Java temporal types (though it mimics them with the Cypher naming for such types). I suppose that neo4j-gremlin in TinkerPop could do conversions, but that doesn't seem like our place to do so imo. I don't see why you wouldn't want to use the Neo4j imports. If you chose to use even `java.util.Date` it's not as though that makes your code portable to other databases (as most of them don't support it either). if you want true portability you will need to store your date as `Long` or ISO-8061 `String`.